# Query with predicate on indexed field

Tags: indexing, hazelcast, query-cache

In my project I recently encountered a problem related to Map with configured QueryCache.

I have entity with two fields:

```
class AccountingRule {
    long key;
    String code;
}
```

Map configuration for it's Map including QueryCache configuration:

```
MapConfig mapConfig = new MapConfig("AccountingRule")
    .setInMemoryFormat(InMemoryFormat.BINARY)
    .setReadBackupData(true)
    .setBackupCount(1)
    .addQueryCacheConfig(new QueryCacheConfig()
        .setName("AccountingRule")
        .setPredicateConfig(new PredicateConfig(TruePredicate.INSTANCE))
        .setIncludeValue(true)
        .setPopulate(true)
        .setDelaySeconds(0)
    );
```

In main I run hazelcast instance with my configuration and then:

- add index to QueryCache
- put entity into IMap
- wait until insertion is propagated to QueryCache by checking if QueryCache.get returned inserted entity
- get same entity from QueryCache using predicate on indexed field

For example:

```
HazelcastInstance hazelcast = createHazelcastInstance();
IMap<Long, AccountingRule> map = hazelcast.getMap("AccountingRule");
QueryCache<Long, AccountingRule> queryCache = map.getQueryCache("AccountingRule");

queryCache.addIndex("code", false);

while (true) {
    AccountingRule ar = newAccountingRule();
    map.put(ar.getKey(), ar);

    // wait for query cache
    AccountingRule fromQueryCache = queryCache.get(ar.getKey());
    while (fromQueryCache == null) {
        log.info("Waiting for query cache");
        fromQueryCache = queryCache.get(AccountingRule.class, ar.getKey());
     }
    log.info("query cache updated");

    // get entity from query cache using predicate
    Predicate codePredicate = equal("code", ar.getCode());
    AccountingRule fromQueryCacheWithPredicate = getOnlyElement(queryCache.values(codePredicate), null);
    if (fromQueryCacheWithPredicate == null) {
        log.error("AccountingRule with id {} from query cash is null", ar.getKey());
        System.exit(1);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately it fails. QueryCache.get returned entity but query based on predicate on indexed field returns nothing. When I wait a little bit and retry query it's ok. It looks like indexes are updated asynchronously am I right? Is there any option to avoid it?

There are two options when it works:

- remove index -> no index no problem :)
- declare index in QueryCache conf like this, not in main:

Code:

```
MapConfig mapConfig = new MapConfig("AccountingRule")
    .setInMemoryFormat(InMemoryFormat.BINARY)
    .setReadBackupData(true)
    .setBackupCount(1)
    .addQueryCacheConfig(new QueryCacheConfig()
        .setName("AccountingRule")
        .setPredicateConfig(new PredicateConfig(TruePredicate.INSTANCE))
        .setIncludeValue(true)
        .setPopulate(true)
        .setDelaySeconds(0)
        .addIndexConfig(new MapIndexConfig("code", false))
    );
```

The question is why when I add index not in configuration it doesn't work properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there is bug regarding this issue. When you execute `QueryCache.addIndex`, the index is only created if there is an entry in the query cache. Moreover, indexes originating from `Config` (programmatic or declarative) are not created at all and the queries run on the query cache does full scan.

I see that you've already created a Github issue regarding this problem ([#12358](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/issues/12358)), please follow it up for the fix.

Comment: You are right about indexes originating from Config. I have done small performance test and it looks like adding index configuration using `QueryCacheConfig.addIndexConfig` does not create index at all.

About `QueryCache.addIndex` it adds index only if QueryCache is empty.